Set-DkimSigningConfig gives InsufficientPermissionException in Exchange Online
We got this tenant that was being administred by a different company. We are currently trying to use New-DkimSigningConfig and  Set-DkimSigningConfig through ExchangeOnline with an App created in Azure. But it keeps giving us this error and we can't seem to find what is going wrong. Know that the tenant has over 10 domains.
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.InsufficientPermissionsException|Source server:--------.EURP1 92.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM doesn't have write permission to target DC:. Usually it indicates that target forest isn't an account  partition of source forest. The user has insufficient access rights.

We have set the right permissions, including Exchange administrator role

We have the CNAME status ok

